# Lapack++ for QR algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, c++, lapack, numerical-analysis

I have recently started using Lapack++ which I found convenient for my programming purpose, in general.

Now, I need to solve a matrix using QR algorithm. I've searched the [user manual](http://lapackpp.sourceforge.net/html/index.html)
and I found a [LaGenQRFactComplex Class](http://lapackpp.sourceforge.net/html/classLaGenQRFactComplex.html#_details) for the purpose. But it need a complex matrix type as input parameter (as per my understanding).

Is there any other way for me to use the same for solving a real valued matrix??

Comment: Welcome to SciComp. You may improve your question and your chances on a quick answer by providing links to the documentation of the package and the particular routines.

Comment: What about LaGenQRFactDouble? (gfqrd.h)